# Problema con foreach en laravel y con If

Tags: laravel, condiciones, foreach

Tengo un problema con una iteraciones, hice un carrito de compras y quiero mostrar un boton dependiendo si la obra ya esta agrega o no, y tengo una vista especial para ver la obra y de ahí agregarla al carrito

Ejemplo:

Si ya agregue una obra a mi carrito quiero que ya aparezca deshabilitado el botón de 'agregar al carrito', y funciona, pero solo cuando tengo una obra, pero cuando tengo mas 2 obras agregadas me muestra un boton habilitado de la otra obra y uno deshabilitado de la obra seleccionada

[image: ejemplo de carrito]

Y cuando quiero mostrar el boton deshabilitado en la obra, me aparece uno por cada obra

[image: ejemplo de botones]

y obviamente solo necesito que se muestre 1,. el que corresponde a la obra, (agregue el id de la obra que esta iterando en el boton para identiicarlos)
y ambas obras ya estan agregadas al carrito

y esta es la iteracion que estoy haciendo

```
 @if (empty($oncart))
            <a href="{{route('obras.addToCart',$obra->id)}}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Añadir a 
 carrito1</button></a>
            @else
               @foreach ($oncart as $o) 
                    @if ($o['item']['id'] == $obra->id  )
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Obra agregada a carrito {{$o['item'] 
  ['id']}}</button>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{route('obras.addToCart',$obra->id)}}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Añadir a carrito {{$o['item']['id']}}</button></a> 
                   @endif 
            @endforeach
      @endif
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes optar por crear un mutador en el modelo de tu Obra.

Asumo que se llama `Obra.php`

Ahí puedes crear una función como la siguiente:

```
public function getIsOnCartAttribute() {
    //Dependiendo de la estructura de tu sistema de carrito lo validas
    foreach($current_cart->obras as $obra){
          if($this->id == $obra->id) { return true; }
    }
    return false;
}
```

En tu blade, solo creas una condición:

```
@if($obra->is_on_cart) // Muestras el botón de ya está agregad

@else
    //Muestras el botón para agregar al carrito
@endif
```

Noté cómo definiste el `foreach()`, solo evita nombrar variables de un solo caracter, usa un nombre que defina bien de lo que se trata, `foreach($cart->obras as $obra)`, evita las variables de un solo caracter a menos que se traten de contadores

Comment: Me funciono perfectamente, muchísimas gracias hermano,

Comment: De nada, considera votar arriba por mi respuesta, saludos.